# How bind variables in SQL statements improve performance of the query - Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

The DBA asked me to replace the const and variable values with the bind parameters in a complex SQL statement to improve the performance of the query. However, I could not understand how it would improve the performance of the query as it would be executing the exact same statement.

I also heard him saying that the bind variables query would get improved with Oracle ***execution plan***, I was reading [this](https://blogs.oracle.com/sql/post/improve-sql-query-performance-by-using-bind-variables) Oracle blog, Could anyone please help to understand the technical detail in simple words? Thank you.

Comment: There's generally no need to parameterize constants. Variables, on the other hand, should be so all queries with different variable values are considered as the same one, and the engine can optimize it once (or few times) and cache it afterwards.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you submit a SQL to Oracle, the database has to set aside shared memory to describe the SQL and generate an execution plan through some complex optimizer permutations and then store its plan (the internal program it generated to fulfill your request). This is what we call a "cursor". It consumes memory and takes time to generate. This happens at the parse step, which if not done explicitly happens implicitly when clients execute SQL. If you were to do this in a loop for a million iterations, using the same SQL but changing some literal identifier each time, you spend an excessive amount of time on this parsing activity and you consume a lot of shared memory, as each SQL is literally different than the one before it and requires its own cursor. At high volume, SQLs using literals that change with each execution can get the database into an unhealthy situation (it can eventually get into problems managing its shared pool which can lead to allocation errors for other users and even crash the database when severe). It also adds unnecessary runtime for the user. Your program is running slower than it should if it has to do a hard parse for each iteration of your loops. So your DBA is correct, this is something we always steer developers away from.

Bind variables allow the same SQL statement (cursor) to be reused repeatedly even though specific predicate values being referenced change from one execution to the next by masking the literal value that's changing each time. Then the SQL text is identical each time and requires only one (hard) parse. Parse once, execute often. This eliminates the expensive overhead of repeatedly hard parsing and the strain of allocating memory in the shared pool and all the pins and latches that requires, thus reducing contention and CPU overhead.

If you find it impossible to implement binds (unlikely), your DBA has the option of creating a logon trigger that intercepts your logons and issues an `alter session` to set "`cursor_sharing=force`" which is an old workaround for this problem, though it can cause issues with some client interfaces and is a last-resort. This setting forcefully rewrites your SQL with every literal replaced with a bind, whether it makes sense to do so or not. That's not ideal, but it's a useful bandaid when code changes can't be made. The best thing is to change the code and use proper bind variables from the client side on predicate values that frequently change.

How you implement binds depends on your programming environment. In PL/SQL it's done simply by using a PL/SQL variable:

```
DECLARE
  var_customer_id number;
  rec_customer customer%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
  var_customer_id := 1234567;

  SELECT *
    INTO rec_customer
    FROM customer
   WHERE customer_id = var_customer_id; -- this cursor can be reused by different customer ID values
END;
```

In SQL Plus you use the `var` declaration:

```
var customer_id number

exec :customer_id := 1234567;

SELECT *
  FROM customer
 WHERE customer_id = :customer_id; -- this cursor can be reused by different customer ids
```

In PHP using the OCI8 instantclient, it might look something like this:

```
   $s = oci_parse($c,"begin
                      :servicecall := myfunction(in_customer_id => :customerid);
                     end;");

  oci_bind_by_name($s,":servicecall",$servicecall,32767);
  oci_bind_by_name($s,":customerid",$customerid,-1, SQLT_INT);

  $r = oci_execute($s);
```

Etc.. Every client programming environment and Oracle interface API is unique, but nearly all should have the concept of a bind. In all cases the literal SQL text contains a placeholder (often with `:`, but not always) and a way to bind a client variable to that placeholder. How you do it depends on what your programming environment is.